# SEO with keywords for a website based on images?

Tags: image, tags, seo, keyword

I have a website with newspapers frontpages so pages contain only big images and no text (neither description, because images change daily).
What's the best way to insert context keywords in the pages?
Is correct insert in body only keywords without link?

Comment: How about adding the alt attribute to the img tags?

Comment: In alt tag I've set newspaper name.

Answer (score 1):

if you can change image names put keywords in those & also use related words, synonyms, plural / singular

also add **alt** & **title** attributes

Answer (score 1):

Even though your pages do not have any content (only images), you still can provide proper page descriptions which will be used by Google (and other search engines).

A couple of handy tips:

- Create unique, accurate page titles using `<title>` tag placed within the `<head>` tag.
- Please bear in mind that Google does not recommend putting keywords into the `title` tag. So it is very good practice to make sure that your title effectively communicates the topic of the page's content.
- Use the `description` meta tag (`<meta name="description" content="">`) to gives any search engine a summary of what the page is about. It is very good practice to use unique descriptions for each page.
- Use the `keywords` meta tag (`<meta name="keywords" content="">`) to give page related keywords.

Also, as far as images are concerned, I would recommend using proper use of `alt` and `title` attributes providing description of your image content. Image names can sometimes be composed of some identifiers which are meaningless for customers.

Please have a look at Matt Cutts Blog page: [Gadgets, Google, and SEO](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/matt-video-alt-attributes-for-images/) where Matt describes in details importance of correct informations in `alt` and `title` attributes of an image tag.